# Is Hibernate mode safe to use?

Tags: windows, ssd, sleep, hibernate

In light of Dell and MS's **vile** decision to disable S3 sleep and only allow S0, I wanted to be able to trust Hibernate mode instead of sleep. I read that there may be some caveats to Hibernate, as it performs a R/W operation of your entire RAM capacity (worst case) every time.

I will say that in my previous laptop which has S3, I used sleep mode a few times every day (driving from one office to another, etc.).

Apart from boot time (I know Hibernate is slower), what do you guys think, is Hibernate a completely trusted mode in terms of wearing down your SSD's performance over time, or affecting any other thing?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is safe to use and doesn't add that much wear to an SSD as long as you don't excessively use it.

You can re-enable S3 sleep if you are on Windows 10 version 20H2 by opening an elevated Command Prompt and copy and paste:

```
reg add HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power /v PlatformAoAcOverride /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```

Comment: Is this Dell specific?